# How to set up multiple django versions on single apache service?

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm using Windows XP and want to know how can I create multiple django versions on a single apache service through virtual host(of course).

I'm trying to do that with one instance of python too. Should i create 1 instance of python for each django version or django needs only its eggs to work, so I can have several eggs in just one python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

put django source anywhere you want and manually specify path to django source in your `manage.py` and `wsgi.py`:

```
import os
os.path.insert(0, 'path-to-django-source');
```

You can also use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Virtualenv fixes paths for console apps automatically, however for `wsgi.py` you still have to write down path's manually.

### Method 2:

Use [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.5.2) and [djangorecipe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe/0.99), it will do all the stuff for you including:

- donwloads django
- download other modules
- creates wsgi.py at `project-dir\bin\wsgi`
- creates manage.py at `project-dir\bin\django.exe`

All this is done with a single config file `buildout.cfg`- here you list your modules and other settings, and then you run a command: `buildout -N`.

However buildout might not be a good solution if you have tight deadlines because there will be things you'll need learn about it but if you are planning to do more python apps I definitely recommend trying it.

Here are some examples for django+buildout setup:

http://www.google.lt/search?q=django+buildout+template+OR+skeleton

### An update to your comment

You cannot install two django versions system wide.

What you can do though is either:

1. Do not install django, just drop the `django-base/django` folder into your project path. You will have to compile the internationalization files manually (if you use i18n):

   ```
    cd django\conf
    python ..\..\manage.py compilemessages
   ```
2. Or, install django with `python setup.py install`, but use extra arguments to change installation destination. Python documentation [covers few different methods](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation).

Comment: I don't wanna use virtualenv, because it seems I can do what I need without it. Change egg location seems great, but if I install 2 versions of django on python, he creates one django folder for them. I'll try it anyway.

Comment: I've added few more lines on how to `install` few django versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in your httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/html/root"
    ErrorLog "/path/to/apache-error.log"
    CustomLog "/path/to/apache-access.log" common

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess djangoapp1
    WSGIProcessGroup djangoapp1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/djangoapp1.wsgi

    Alias /static /path/to/static/files

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:81
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:81>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/html/root"
    ErrorLog "/path/to/apache-error.log"
    CustomLog "/path/to/apache-access.log" common

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess djangoapp2
    WSGIProcessGroup djangoapp2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/djangoapp2.wsgi

    Alias /static /path/to/static/files

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</VirtualHost>
```

And then, in your djangoapp1.wsgi/djangoapp2.wsgi script you can define the different django versions and applications:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('')
sys.path.append('/path/to/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/path/to/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg ')
... etc ...
sys.path.append('/path/to/djangoapp1/src')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djangoapp1.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```